# Java characters alignment algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two arrays of 100 characters(maximum, could be less or not the same size) that I want to align. I want to add an "-" when there is a character different than the other. I found the [Needleman–Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) algorithm, which is based on dynamic programming, and the [Smith–Waterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) algorithm which is a general local alignment method also based on dynamic programming but they seems too complex for what I want to do. I just need a simple algorithm in Java perhaps about less than 50 lines, this code will be translated to assembly language after, so that why I need a simple algorithm.

Is there a way do this kind of alignment with a diff algorithm ? If yes can someone point me how to do this ? I searched on the biostar section, but it seems pretty much that I need to use the two algorithm I mentioned.

English is not my native language, so perhaps I searched the wrong keywords.

My program already works with the Needleman algorithm and its about 200 (ish) lines of code.

Example of desired input/output:

```
Input
Array 1 : MKNLASREVNIYVNGKLV
Array 2 : QMASREVNIYVNGKL


Output
Array 1 (or a simple print) : -MKNLASREVNIYVNGKLV 
Array 2 (or a simple print) : QM---ASREVNIYVNGKL-
```

Comment: Is the output correct? `IY` disappeared, while `Q` still remains? Is the order of Array 2 relevant, or does it simply follow Array 1 order?

Comment: I modified the input output to make the problem clearer, and order is relevant.

Comment: In the Wikipedia article, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment, those are basically the only algorithms listed. It's unlikely that the internets will be able to come up with something better. Besides, how is your problem scenario any **simpler** than the general sequence alignment case?

Comment: @Andrew In my case performance is not an issue. Simplicity is the issue, because it will be translated to assembly language. The algorithms I mentioned are efficient and quick, but fairly complex and use dynamic or weith algorithm, that I cant translate. I didnt want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a variation of Levenshtein distance that does exactly what you want:

Output

```
-MKNLASREVNIYVNGKLV
QM---ASREVNIYVNGKL-
```

Code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] aligned = align("MKNLASREVNIYVNGKLV", "QMASREVNIYVNGKL");
        System.out.println(aligned[0]);
        System.out.println(aligned[1]);
    }

    public static String[] align(String a, String b) {
        int[][] T = new int[a.length() + 1][b.length() + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length(); i++)
            T[i][0] = i;

        for (int i = 0; i <= b.length(); i++)
            T[0][i] = i;

        for (int i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= b.length(); j++) {
                if (a.charAt(i - 1) == b.charAt(j - 1))
                    T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j - 1];
                else
                    T[i][j] = Math.min(T[i - 1][j], T[i][j - 1]) + 1;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder aa = new StringBuilder(), bb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = a.length(), j = b.length(); i > 0 || j > 0; ) {
            if (i > 0 && T[i][j] == T[i - 1][j] + 1) {
                aa.append(a.charAt(--i));
                bb.append("-");
            } else if (j > 0 && T[i][j] == T[i][j - 1] + 1) {
                bb.append(b.charAt(--j));
                aa.append("-");
            } else if (i > 0 && j > 0 && T[i][j] == T[i - 1][j - 1]) {
                aa.append(a.charAt(--i));
                bb.append(b.charAt(--j));
            }
        }

        return new String[]{aa.reverse().toString(), bb.reverse().toString()};
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant ! Much simpler and cleaner !

Comment: Mind adding some explanation of what your algorithm doesn't do compared to general sequence alignment?

Comment: It can't assign weights to "edit operations" based on the operation itself nor their position on the string. Of course it's easy to modify it to do so. There is a more generalized version of this algorithm called [Smith-Waterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

The description of your problem immediately makes me think of the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and its related algorithm, which is simple (definitely less than 50 lines) but is based on dynamic programming too.

The original algorithm just calculates the number of changes required, but it can be easily modified to find the required insertions, deletions and substitutions. Actually I'm not sure if you even want to handle substitutions, how would you align for example ABC and ADC?